# How can I delete a dkms module in (arch) linux?

Tags: linux, kernel, archlinux, dkms

I have a dkms module. I wanted to remove it. I did `sudo dkms remove ...`. But when I update to a newer kernel, my package manager tries to build that module and failed, so it added it again.

How do I prevent that and remove the module?

Comment: Can you please post the output of pacman when installing a newer kernel? Are you sure that the module's DKMS tarball or folder is not present in the ```/usr/src``` directory? And also ```/var/lib/dkms/``` ?

Answer (score 9):

To remove the module, you need to run sudo dkms remove modul/version --all
to prevent it from being rebuilt during the next update, you must also remove the sources under /usr/src/.

here is an example of how to remove akvcam module

```
dkms status
```

akvcam, 1.2.0, 5.12.14-arch1-1, x86_64: installed

```
sudo dkms remove akvcam/1.2.0 --all
sudo rm -rf /usr/src/akvcam-1.2.0/
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/akvcam.conf
```

good luck
marco manngatter

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to Ubuntu, and this saved a lot of headache for me.

Comment: Is it necessary to `rm /var/lib/dkms/{module}` too or is that what the `dkms remove` cmd is essetially doing?

Comment: In my case, I have to delete `/var/lib/dkms/{module}` as some module version won't be deleted with command `dkms remvoe {module}/{version} --all`